# how to by pass multiple claim authentication login page in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-server, claims-based-auth

My Requirement is

I have SharePoint Server 2013.Now I just added two AD FS Server 3.0 and configured to SharePoint site http://spsxyz with Claim based authentication.

An example of My Server Setup:

Sharepoint server - XYZ -- Domain Controller --XYZ.COM   (Test User Sam)

ABC AD FS Server  -- ABC -- Domain Controller -- ABC.COM  (Test User John)

CONTOSO AD FS Server -- CONTOSO -- Domain Controller -- CONTOSO.COM  ( Test User Alex)

I already added Sam, John, Alex in the SharePoint site

My Requirement:

When the user opens the SharePoint page, it will be asking to select Authentication types like Windows or ABC Domain Users or CONTOSO Domain users.

when the user login the SharePoint page then it will bypass multiple authentication page and login to correct SharePoint page.

How can I achieve this task?

Task Tried and Failure:

1. I just tried to created custom Login page and entered /_trust/ in custom sign option on the web application.

It is not working and is not able to debug the code and if I open the SharePoint page it is always redirecting to ABC AD FS and open SP Page.

**Implementing in this task** I am  not sure this is right track

So I am trying to create custom HTTP handler to bypass the login page.

2. I created custom HTTP handler and deployed in _layout folder and I am not able to get proper domain name inside the code, if I get domain name then I will use IF conduit

If I am Using SharePoint Object model and getting current user
on and redirect the proper domain AD FS Server and Also facing an issue

how to redirect SharePoint https://spsxyz login page to custom handler page .ashx, so I am researching on this

Urgently Please help me if anyone knows how to bypass multiple authentications in the SharePoint 2013 login page.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read your requirements then it's out of the box functionality, so no need to write any code.

Configure SharePoint to accept logins from the two other domains' ADFS servers (see TechNet: [Configure SAML-based claims authentication with AD FS in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305235.aspx)) and it should just work:
When users access SharePoint they'll be asked to select authentication method:

1. Windows
2. ABC AD FS
3. CONTOSO AD FS

When they select they'll be logged in (provided that ADFS are in an appropriate zone)

Comment: thanks for your comments, I already configured and added other domain users in my sharepoint page, but customer dont want to select authentication method.. how can i skip the authentication selection page,If ABC user logged In the sharepoint site then  it should automatically log into their page.

Comment: You will not be able to select authentication method based on who has logged in, as you won't be able to determine who the user is until they have authenticated to SharePoint. And in order to do that you have to select an authentication method.

Comment: If the users in the three domains come from different IP-ranges you might be able to use something like https://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/, but I haven't tried it myselves

Comment: I tired Spautosign in it doesn't work,  
I just edit change the loginUrl property of the webconfig <forms> tag to point to my custom HTTP handler https://spsxyz/_layouts/TestClaimhandler/Testhand.ashx 
Using the below code, I am not getting IE user name. NULL object reference error SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web; SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() { using (SPSite ElevatedsiteColl = new SPSite(siteColl.ID)) { using (SPWeb ElevatedSite = ElevatedsiteColl.OpenWeb(site.ID)) { string currUser = site.CurrentUser; //not the ElevatedSite.CurrentUser } } });

Comment: how can I get current Internet Explorer domain and user name via any codings